# CSS+HTML for this mockup?

Tags: html, css, colors

I got a mockup that I want to realize with CSS+HTML.

[image]

I started a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/ENKBV/1/) for it that is just a table that I wonder if you can help me make the style for.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>grey</td>
        <td>grey</td>
        <td>grey</td>
        <td>grey</td>
        <td>grey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>COL1</td>
        <td>COL2</td>
        <td>COL3</td>
        <td>COL4</td>
        <td>icon1|icon2|icon3|icon4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make every second row grey? Should I keep a serverside variable and calculate a mod 2 or is there some easier way that with CSS make every other row grey and white?

Comment: Got bored so I made a fiddle of the style you want. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ENKBV/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this whether this helps you Bro : 
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ENKBV/2/)

```
table{ width:100%; text:align:center;border:1px solid #00F; font-size:12px;}
th{background:#EEE;width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
td{width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #EEE;}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use even or odd. css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

You can even make columns:

```
col:first-child {background: #FF0}
col:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #CCC}
```

Good link with demo: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

And yes this is css3 technique, will not work on all browsers. If you want cross browser support, use create class .even {} and use php to echo it on even line, or js to do the same.

Comment: Should probably state somewhere that this is using CSS3 and limits browser support.